# Is $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ a semisimple $\mathbb{Z}$-module?

Tags: modules, cyclic-groups

Since $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ is an abelian group of order $4$, $4=2^2$, and $2$ is a prime, we know $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$. So $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ is semisimple as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, right?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Could you expand on your thought? And make it clear semi-simple *as what*?

Comment: Well, I never knew that! For decades, I'd assumed those groups were non-isomorphic. I even thought I could prove that!

Comment: I notice you tagged this question `cyclic-groups`, however only one of the two groups you claim are isomorphic is cyclic.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Fyhswdsxjj: What everyone is trying to tell you more or less subtly is that $\mathbb Z/4$ is **not** isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/2 \oplus \mathbb Z/2$, whatever reason you might falsely believe to have for that. Look e.g. at orders of elements.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Ok! I will. $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ has an element of order $4$, while the maximal order of the elements in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is $2$, so they can not be isomorphic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice you posted another question regarding the socle of $\mathbb{Z}_{16} \times \mathbb{Z}_{25}$. In my answer to that question there is a characterization of the socle of $\mathbb{Z}_m$ for general $m \in \mathbb{N}^*$. In this particular case, the socle of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ (this can be seen very easily, even without resorting to the systematized theory I presented a bit of in my answer to the above mentioned question, since $\mathbb{Z}_4$ has only one nontrivial proper submodule, which happens to be simple); as the module in question contains its socle as a proper submodule, it cannot be semisimple.

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!